# Adding an element to the end in linked list C program

Tags: c, list, struct

This program is meant to insert an element in the middle of a linked list, but I left out functions that aren't in question.

At first I wrote it with assigning HEAD and CURRENT elements to NULL globally and it worked fine. With locally assigned variables in `main()` it doesn't work. Specifically, the `while` loop in `main` is infinite because of the faulty `insertDataToEnd` function. How could I fix it? Also, before I wrote `insertDataToEnd` differently and it printed only first and last elements of the list, could the problem be with `printList` ?

EDIT (again): still having some issues processing all the new information on structures. Now I have this sortList function to swap elements so they would be in inclining order. I get an error only when the function is used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;

void insertDataToEnd(int value, struct node **head){
    struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    link -> data = value;
    link -> next = NULL;
    node_t *current = *head;
    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = link;
    }
    else{
        while(current -> next != NULL){
        current = current -> next;
        }
    current -> next = link;

    }
}

void printList(struct node* head){
    node_t *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d -> ", current -> data);
        current = current -> next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

void sortList(int count, struct node* head){
    int i, j, temp;
    count += 1;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        current = head;
        next = current -> next;
        for(j = 1; j < count + 1; j++){
            if(current -> data > next -> data){
                temp = current -> data;
                current -> data = next -> data;
                next -> data = temp;
            }
            current = current->next;
            next = next->next;
        }
    }
}

void insertElement(int value, int k, struct node** head){
    node_t *elemk = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *elem = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(node_t));
    elemk = *head;
    int i = 2;
    while (i < k && elemk != NULL){
        elemk = elemk -> next;
        i++;
    }
    if(i == k){
        printf("element inserted.\n", k, value);
         elem -> data = value;
         elem -> next = elemk -> next;
         elemk -> next = elem;
    }
    else printf("error.\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int value, readValue, k;
    int i = 0;
    printf("enter data.\n");
    while(1){
        scanf("%d", &value);
        insertDataToEnd(value, &head);
        i++;
        if (i == 4) break;
    }
    sortList(i, head);
    printf("insert element\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &readValue, &k);
    insertElement(readValue, k, &head);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `calling insertDataToEnd(value, current);` doesn't modify `current`? BTW what is `sortList` ?

Comment: Hint: you need `**` in `insertDataToEnd`, similar to what has been done in `insertFirstElement`. The `printList` function looks OK.

Comment: Another hint: you don't need a `insertFirstElement` and a `insertDataToEnd` function. You can write _one single_ function that handles the case where `head`is NULL. This would also simplify the `main` function.

Comment: I understand that (**) but then the function itself has to change a bit, doesn't it? because if i simply make current to *current, it won't work...

Comment: Yes, of course `insertDataToEnd` has to undergo some changements. If you understand how `insertFirstElement` (which is correct) works, you should be able to find out how to modify `insertDataToEnd`.

Comment: (at edit ver) `current -> next = link;` move to after while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing top much work. The only thing that changes is that a pointer that used to be NULL gets a new value: a pointer to the freshly created object.

- for an empty list this will be the *root* pointer
- in any other case: it will be the next/link pointer of the last node on the linked list
- task one: find the position of this null pointer
- and yes: we'll need a pointer to it, since we want change its value

---

```
void insertDataToEnd(int value, struct node **head){

        /* find (pointer to) the NULL pointer on the list */
    for( ;*head == NULL; head = (*head)->next) {;}

        /* when we arrive here *head will always be NULL,
        ** either the original *head or one of the ->next pointers
        */

         // create new node and assign its pointer to the found pointer */
    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
    (*head)->data = value;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

---

If you want to insert into the middle of the list, you just want to change the loop logic a bit, and jump out of it once the insertion point is found:

```
void insertDatasomewhere(int value, struct node **head){
    struct node *temp;        

        /* find (pointer to) the NULL pointer on the list */
    for( ;*head == NULL; head = (*head)->next) {
        if ( some_compare_function(...) break;
        }

        /* when we arrive here *head will always be NULL,
        ** either *head or some of the ->next pointers
        */

         // create new node and assign its pointer to the found pointer */
    temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    temp->next = *head;
    temp->data = value;
    *head = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but these functions of mine already work and they don't seem too complicated as I understand. the only issue I have now is with sortList function just to print all the values in incline order. I can't figure that out...

Comment: Make a drawing. Use pen & paper. In fact: make *two* drawings: one before, and on after the insertion. (and: for linked lists sorting is basically a bunch of insertions and deletions)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly the variable `current` plays the role of the tail of the list. In this case there is no need to pass it as an argument to the function `insertFirstElement`. The variable can be assigned in main.

So the functions can be written the following way

```
int insertFirstElement( node_t **head, int data )
{
    node_t *elem = malloc( sizeof( node_t) );
    int success = elem != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        elem->data = data;
        elem->next = *head;

        *head = elem;
    }

    return success;
}

int insertDataToEnd( node_t **tail )
{
    node_t *elem = malloc( sizeof( node_t) );
    int success = elem != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        elem->data = data;
        elem->next = NULL;

        if ( *tail ) ( *tail )->next = elem;

        *tail = elem;
    }

    return success;
}
```

In main after for example a call of the function `insertFirstElement` you should write

```
if ( current == NULL ) current = head;
```

Answer (score 0):

> the only issue I have now is with sortList function

You miscounted the possible loop cycles when you wrote

```
        for(j = 1; j < count + 1; j++){
```

in `sortList()`, and so the function tries to access `next -> data` when there is no next element. You'd better not use a counter for the loop condition; the minimum change is to replace the above line with:

```
        while (next)
        {
```